# Name of metric: percentage of K for 100% recall

Tags: recommender-system, metric

I have a recommendation system problem where full recall is important. Thus, the standard metrics of recall@k is insufficient. Rather, what I want to measure is how much of the recommendations must be used to get 100% recall.

I am computing `k_for_full_recall = k@r[100%] / MAX_K`, and take the average of this metric across queries.

- Is there is a name for this metric? Where can I read more about such a metric?
- Should I be using a different metric?  How does one evaluate recommender systems where 100% recall is critical?